# Find element after this in collection of all with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given these two variables:

```
var all = $('audio');
var specific = $(this);
```

Where `all` includes `specific`, how do I find the element that comes *after* `specific` in the `all` collection?

---

**Purpose:** When one audio element ends playing, I want to start the next one automatically.

```
$('audio')
    .each(function(){
        this.onended = onEnded;
    });

function onEnded(event)
{
    var next = ?;
    next.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `index()` with a selector to match:

```
var current = specific.index('audio'),
    next = all.eq(current + 1);
```

Or, to loop back to the first if there is no 'next' audio element:

```
    next = all.eq(current + 1 < all.length ? current + 1 : 0);
```

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Is this safe current is the last element?

Comment: Well, you'd have to check that `next` is less than `all.length` I guess, but it should be 'safe' enough I think. Edited to add an alternative that checks, and loops back to the first `audio` if there's no 'next' to play.

Comment: Tested it out now, and seems to work great! Will have to add `index` to my jQuery repertoire, hehe.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped!